# Interstitial not showing after Proguard

Tags: admob, proguard, google-play-services

I'm updating to the new version of Google Play Services, where the AdMob library is now included.  (Furthermore, it seems you must change to the included AdMob api, since [you cannot also include the old AdMob .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721158).)

The problem: Interstitials are showing as they should when I run a debug build straight from Eclipse, they are showing as they should when I export an .apk without using Proguard, but when I run it through Proguard they no longer show.  In the log I get this when the ad should be shown:

```
11-04 21:05:35.023: W/Ads(27590): Could not get info for ad overlay.
11-04 21:05:35.078: W/InputMethodManagerService(261): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4205b940 attribute=null
```

Banner ads are working, but not interstitials.  I tried adding `-keep class com.google.**` to `progruad-project.txt`, but that did not help.  Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it by adding this line to proguard-project.txt:

```
 -keep public class com.google.** {*;}
```

In case of using mediation it is also necessary to add this lines:

```
-keep public class yourMediationAdNetwork.* {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}
```

Replace "yourMediationAdNetwork" for your Ad Network. For example, if you are using "AppFlood":

```
-keep public class com.appflood.* {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}
```