# Show Admob banner in android 2.1 using google play services library

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am stuck in a strange problem. I a creating an app which has something to do with google plus only when its running on android 2.3 or above. So I use Google Play Services Library for the purpose. The library runs on 2.3 and above.

Now even if I wish to do google plus stuff on 2.3 and above, I want my app to be capable of showing ads from android 2.1 . But this is not sort of possible because admob is now integrated in Google Play Services Library which does not support 2.1 . I cannot even include a separate Jar for admob because using both admob jar and play services library simultaneously gives multiple dex file error at compile time.

Is there any real solution to the problem ? Thanks

Comment: I was looking for an answer for this question but then I found someone asked the same here and it seems that we have to use google play services and no other opitions if we use both libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721158/utilize-both-play-services-and-admob-sdk

Comment: Also it got mentioned here in the google open source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63007   I hope they gonna fix it asap!