# Google Mobile Ads - get publisher provided location

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

[**Google Mobile Ads**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/01/google-play-services-41.html)

> With Google Play services 4.1, the Google Mobile Ads SDK now fully
>   supports DoubleClick for Publishers, DoubleClick Ad Exchange, and
>   Search Ads for Mobile Apps. You can also use a new publisher-provided
>   location API to provide Google with the location when requesting ads.
>   Location-based ads can improve your app monetization.

How to get publisher provided location? How to set the retrived location to `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest`?

Comment: Google said the apis and docs would be released once the rollout of play services 4.1 is complete, which as far as I know hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you can receive user's location using standart Android methods (https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) and set location in AdRequest using this method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html#setLocation(android.location.Location)

This question also may be helpful:
[How to supply location with an AdRequest now that AdMob has become part of the Google Play Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718165/how-to-supply-location-with-an-adrequest-now-that-admob-has-become-part-of-the-g)

Answer (score 1):

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .setLocation(Location l)
    .build();
```

This works for me.

Comment: I used this by passing latitude & longitude of particular country say US. But in  adMob console it doesn't show the same country. Do you know why this is happening ?